# Couchbase: What is the most efficient way to find the parent of a nested document?

Tags: couchbase

Assume:

```
{  
   "id":"parent1",
   "name":"parent-name",
   "children":[  
      {  
         "id":"child1",
         "name":"child1-name"
      },
      {  
         "id":"child2",
         "name":"child2-name"
      }
   ]
}
```

Knowing the child1 id, I would like to formulate a query to find out the id of its parent.

I have seen that SATISFIES condition but I was looking for more ways to efficiently figure out who the parent is since creating a query with a SATISFIES clause would probably iterate through all the children (linear).

Comment: If this is the primary use of the data set, then it might be best to flatten the hierarchy, creating each child with a "ParentId" attribute.

Comment: @theMayer by flatten, do you mean creating separate documents for each child object?